# Как работает переадрессация с запрещенного у Роскомнадзора

Tags: сеть, https, redirect, dns

Иногда зайдя на сайт, браузер может переадрессовать на страницу, где напечатано, что ресурс заблокирован роскомнадзором.
Как провайдер это делает?

Я знаю, что у провайдеров есть DPI, который анализирует твой трафик. Если DPI обнаруживает запрос к запрещенному, он делает редирект(на сайт с табличкой запрета). Но почему работает redirect несмотря на HSTS? Я имею в виду, если провайдер это делает с помощью подмены(спуффинга) DNS, то с HSTS+HTTPS (если HTTPS сайт находится в preload lists или уже был посещен, то сайт автоматически идет на HTTPS) это некатит, т.к. с подменой DNS браузер выдаст предупреждение о фиговом сертификате. Но редирект у РКН нормально проходит. (Еще интереснее, редирект у меня идет с HTTPS сайта на HTTP сайт, http://erblock.crimea.com).

**Значит они это делают как-то по другому, но как?**

Comment: Не верю ©
Скорее всего вы что-то путаете и запрос таки идёт по http

Comment: Покажите конкретный пример с `curl`/`wget` или хотя бы скриншот из инструментов разработчика где видно что запрос был по https и ответ был не от сайта.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, да похоже я ошибся. То есть нет вообще никакой возможности перенаправить с https сайта на что то другое(сайт роутера например)

Comment: Одна из основных целей https именно в этом и состоит, что бы никто не мог незаметно подсматривать и подменять трафик. Так что нет, в рамках нормальной работы https нельзя.